# Laravel routes, two registration forms on one page

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a registration form. On one page /pages/register i have two forms. One for "register as a person" and one for "register as a company".

Form one has `action="{{ route('frontend.persons.store') }}"` on it and it works.

When i create the second form with 
`action="{{ route('frontend.companies.store') }}"`

it stops working with error

> "Route [frontend.persons.store] not defined."

The problem is that the routes are defined.

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/pages/register', 'Frontend\PagesController@register')->name('register'); (returns a view)

Route::post('/pages/register', 'Frontend\FrontendPersonsController@store')->name('frontend.persons.store');

Route::post('/pages/register', 'Frontend\FrontendCompaniesController@store')->name('frontend.companies.store');
```

I am using Laravel Framework 5.8.11

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: Tried, doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've two identical URI's for two different controller method, as a result only the first one works, but when you try to fire second one the error undefined route throws up.

> /pages/register

```
Route::post('/pages/register', 'Frontend\FrontendPersonsController@store')->name('frontend.persons.store');
```

> /pages/register

```
Route::post('/pages/register', 'Frontend\FrontendCompaniesController@store')->name('frontend.companies.store');
```

try changing the either route, for example

```
 Route::post('/pages/company/register', 'Frontend\FrontendCompaniesController@store')->name('frontend.companies.store');
```